# Additional information w/ Facebook API?

Tags: php, sql, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm thinking about integrated Facebook's API features with my website.  Not looking for too much data from facebook... just name, email, location.  There are some additional fields that I need.  My website helps connect folks that are affiliated with the military and a particular university, so I ask "duty location", "rank", and a few other bits of information on my registration form (form --> mySQL).

Is there anyway to ask this additional information when users opt to login with facebook?

Otherwise, do you know of any other way that I can incorporate facebook's power into my website?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Have them log in via Facebook. Once they log in, present them with a form to supply the additional data.

Comment: How does this process work then?  They log in via Facebook.  Information such as email, first_name, last_name, etc. is pulled from Facebook and stored in my SQL database?  Then I redirect them to a form, and that information added to the SQL database?